# Backspace Acting like Enter in Bash

Tags: bash, sco

Whenever I type a mistake into my SCO machine, using `bash`, I press <kbd>backspace</kbd> and it is like pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, but doesn't execute the command.

e.g.

```
bash-3.1$ ifcomfig "(backspace)"
bask-3.1$
```

But if I pressed <kbd>enter</kbd>, then it would be like this:

```
bash-3.1$ ifcomfig "(enter)"
bash: ifcomfig: command not found
```

- **Why is it doing this?**
- **And how can I fix this?**

Thank you

**Update**

Here is the output of `stty -a`:

```
speed 38400 baud;   ispeed 38400 baud;   ospeed 38400 baud;   line = 0(tty);
rows = 100; columns = 92; ypixels = 0; xpixels = 0;
intr = DEL; quit = ^\; erase = DEL; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ^@;
swtch = <undef>; susp = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -cstopb hupcl cread -clocal -loblk
-ortsfl -ctsflow -rtsflow
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl -iuclc
-ixon -ixany -ixoff
isig icanon -xcase echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh
-iexten -tostop -xclude
opost -olcuc onlcr -ocrnl -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel
-isscancode
-autoe -ed_emacs -ed_vi -ed_history
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `stty -a`?

Comment: Updated description.

Comment: I see that it shows: `erase = DEL`, but the Delete button adds a `~` to the line. I'm not sure that is what is meant by: `erase = DEL` though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible that the backspace key on the keyboard may actually be generating  the DEL character. That's sort of confirmed by the fact that *both* `intr` and `erase` are set to `DEL` according to your `stty -a` output. I have no idea which one would be given priority in that case since I've never been foolish enough to try it :-) <sup>(a)</sup>

A quick way to confirm would be to enter:

```
stty intr '^C'
```

in your terminal session, which will change it to CTRL-C and *then* see what backspace does.

If that then starts working okay, you need to find where the `intr` keystroke is being set and stop it from happening, or just set it to `^C` as the last thing in your profile (overriding the errant setting).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Although, actually, I've just given it a shot by setting both my `intr` and `erase` to `^?` (my backspace character), and the interrupt nature takes over.

Comment: Genius!!! Thank you, it has worked properly now.

Comment: @paxdiablo Beat me to it : )

Comment: Sorry, @djf, I don't normally hang out here (I'm an SO guy mostly), I just came over to check up on my SLES11 question and got carried away :-)

Comment: @djf, haha I knew you were going to give an answer. But thanks for asking me for that `stty -a`

Comment: @paxdiablo @Kevdog777 No problem. I'm glad you could fix it using `stty`. I my mind I was already falling down the Termcap/Terminfo rabbit hole... you don't wanna go there.

Comment: @paxdiablo: it sure looks like you are an SO guy, whoa! Thanks again. So I have just done `stty intr '^C'`, will that stay when I log off? Or do I need to add it to my `.profile` as well?

Comment: @Kevdog777: No, that'll only do it for the current terminal. You need to put it somewhere where it's run every login (such as the profile).

Comment: I added the `stty intr '^C'` to my .profile (as a test user - /u/test/.profile) and logged off and back on, and it is back to the old problem.

Comment: @Kev, you need to look into what profile scripts are running when you "log on". Whether .profile, .bash_profile, .bashrc and a host of other files are run is controlled by how you're logging on and off (eg. via text mode or gdm for example). Bottom line, if you "log in" and stty -a shows the old setting, then .profile wasn't run. That's a totally different problem. Unfortunately, I have no experience with SCO UNIX.

Comment: Sweet! It was using my `.bashrc` config file.